# Gulp doesn't ignore SASS partials with underscore

Tags: css, sass, gulp, visual-studio-2015

My tasks are as follows:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
gulp.src(paths.webroot + '/css/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + '/css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
gulp.watch(paths.webroot + 'css/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

My folder structure:

```
css
  libs
     _partial1.scss
     _partial2.scss
  main.scss
```

How can I ignore all files with underscore or go after only top level files in `css` (ignoring `libs`)

Answer (score 0):

To go after only top level files in `css/` and ignore `css/libs`, do:

`gulp.src(paths.webroot + '/css/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + '/css'));
});`

I'm guessing you're already importing the partials in your `main.scss` or some other top level file.