# Ignoring SCSS/SASS partials in Gulp task

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I've got the following structure:

```
├── assets
│   └── css
│       └── output.css
├── gulpfile.js
├── index.html
├── package.json
└── scss
    ├── some-other.css
    ├── _base.scss
    ├── _config.scss
    ├── _helpers.scss
    ├── _home.scss
    └── main.scss
```

I'm using Gulp to compile the CSS and SCSS files in `scss/` into one file in `assets/css/`. This is the relevant task from my `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
  return gulp.src(['scss/**/*.scss','scss/**/*.css'])
    .pipe(concat('output.css'))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});
```

The problem is that my SCSS/SASS partials (those files starting with an underscore in `scss/` get fed through the the task and ultimately fail.

I'd like to ignore the files anywhere in `scss/` that start with an underscore and end with `.scss`.

I've taken a look at the following but I wasn't able to get it to work:

- [Gulp doesn't ignore SASS partials with underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657255/gulp-doesnt-ignore-sass-partials-with-underscore)
- [How can I use a glob to ignore files that start with an underscore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689351/how-can-i-use-a-glob-to-ignore-files-that-start-with-an-underscore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that I was mislead and using the suggestions in the linked questions I was actually able to get this working with the following:

```
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('scss/**/[^_]*.?(s)css')
    .pipe(concat('output.css'))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});
```

Sorry for the noise - I should have been more thorough in my testing before asking the question. Hope this helps someone, though.